# Highchart + IE = Greyscale Exports?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, png, jpeg

So... basically what the title says...

When using the export button on any of our charts in IE (tested in 10, I'm assuming all) the downloaded png or jpg is black and white. But the exact same chart in Chrome downloads fine.

Any idea what would be causing this?

Comment: Do you have the same issue when testing any of the [demos](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but checking that just made me think of updating the plugin. Seems to be an issue with an old version, new plugin works fine albeit making a few of our charts a little buggy. 

Thanks for the brainstorming!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out updating the Highcharts plugin to the newest one fixed the issue.